# C# multiple app instances with same connection string - max pool size reached

Tags: c#, connection-string, max-pool-size

1. There is a class library which describes a class called ServerTools that creates a connection to a database, and the connection string is hardcoded (not my code) with pool size = 10.
2. My application creates an instance of ServerTools and uses canonized Parallel.Foreach to query the db. I control the connection resources using a semaphore. (The P.FE loop runs according to user input so I can't predict how many threads the TPL will create, that's why I control the db connections using a semaphore and not by limiting the number of created threads).
3. For unrelated reasons, I need to run 3 instances of my app.

So eventually, I have 3 instances of my app, using 30 connections to the db.

When I ran these instances from different machines, everything was OK.

When I run these instances from the same machine, although these are different instances, I get an error saying:

"The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

So my question is: 
Is the connection pool configured per IP? I thought it will be configured per instance.
Is there any work around other than running my instances using different machines? If some code changes were made so that each instance of ServerTools will have a different connection string, by making minor changes to the connection string so that the connection string won't be exactly the same, would it work?

Thanks!

Comment: The connection pool is per process, it means one of your single programs reached the pool size, which is by default 100 connections for the same connection string. However, if you manage to circumvent this by manually tucking on something on the connection string so that different pools are used you will just tax the database server more because you're keeping excessive number of connections to the database open.

Comment: Unless you talk to a web service, then the pool may be in the web service and be shared across all the clients (because the pool is in just 1 process, the web service application), but it doesn't sound like this is your case.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's exactly the point, I want to tax the database more than the defined max pool size at the connection string. It can handle it :)

Comment: Then perhaps just up the size of the connection pool? [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx): `...; Max Pool Size=200` ?

Comment: If you are hosting the web service in IIS, an easy workaround is to configure it to use individual processes. A less easy workaround (and in fact what I'd call overkill) is to run your tasks in separate AppDomains. If you have any way at all of varying the connection string, then yes, even insignificant changes (like adding a semicolon) will cause them to count as different connections for the purpose of connection pooling, but as @LasseV.Karlsen points out, if you have *any* way of changing it a much better option is to say what you mean.

Comment: Clarification: I don't have a web service in IIS.
Regarding the connections string - since it is hard coded (written at the c# code) at the class library I'm using, I don't want to change the max pool size since other apps (not maintained by me) also use this dll.
I can, however, change the code, and perhaps make minor random changes to the connection string in order to get a 'clean pool' every time an instance is created. Will test and update.

Comment: "I don't want to change the max pool size since other apps (not maintained by me) also use this dll." The clean approach would then be to add a hook (constructor parameter, property, whatever) where you can configure the pool size, falling back to the default of 10 if this option is not used, so existing clients are unaffected. Tweaking the connection string is an ugly hack and not at all obvious to future maintainers. Unless the source isn't available and the original developer is dead (or something equally dire), reducing hardcoding is never a bad idea.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right. this is ugly, and a ctor param should be used. But since the number of instances may differ every couple of weeks, I'll have to make sure that each instance's pool size param is the same (let's say 30), cause If I'll make a mistake and the pool sizes will be different, I will overload the server way more than now.
That's why I think that although it's ugly, making minor changes to the connection string may be better (and get a new pool for each instance)

Comment: Besides, I don't get how come a different instance doesn't get a new pool. this is weird. What if I had different apps which connect to the same db using the same connection string? would they share the pool? it doesn't make any sense

Comment: What is an "app" in your world? A connection pool is per-AppDomain, and if you don't create multiple AppDomains, then one process has one AppDomain. One process, one pool. If you really are creating separate processes, then each of these can have no more than 10 connections. This setup works the same as using different machines, except that you have only one range of outgoing TCP/IP ports, and only one OS to limit how many connections you can open per second, and only one OS to host shared objects (like named, global semaphores). Could any of those be your problem instead?